# How can I get some additional information from an EF DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 5 and doing an update. I get the following exception and using the SQL Profiler I don't see any SQL issued:

```
    catch (DbUpdateException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, ex);
    }
```

The message with this says:

```
{System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_QuestionQuestionStatus". The conflict occurred in database "TestDb", table "dbo.QuestionStatus", column 'QuestionStatusId'.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at TestDb.Models.Contexts.TestDbContext.SaveChanges() in c:\K\ST134 Aug 14\TestDb.Models\Contexts\TestDbContext.cs:line 101
   at TestDb.Services.TestDbUowBase.Commit() in c:\K\ST135 Aug 15\TestDb.Services\TestDbUowBase.cs:line 48
   at TestDb.Web.Controllers.ProblemController.PostProblem(Problem problem) in c:\K\ST135 Aug 15\WebUx\Controllers\ProblemController.cs:line 99}
```

Usually I can find a clue with the exception but in this case I cannot see anything useful in the exception listing. Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could find out more?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The message:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_QuestionQuestionStatus". The conflict occurred in database "TestDb", table "dbo.QuestionStatus", column 'QuestionStatusId'.
```

sounds quite precise i think. Check, if your entity has set all (required) foreign keys to a valid value.

Comment: Thanks. I spent too much time looking at the details to see that.  I will know where to look next time. Do you know if there is a place in the exception stack where I could extract this information from so I could send it to the log.

Comment: no problem, i learned reading EF exceptions the hard way :) please accept this answer if it helped to solve your problem